# Cocoapods not generating targets

Tags: ios, cocoapods, target, xcode7.3

I'm encountering an issue where whenever I update or add a new library in my podfile and run a `pod install`, cocoapods is not creating a build target for that library; this makes adjusting a specific pod's build settings impossible.

Specifically, the latest GoogleMap pod, GoogleAnalytics pod, and MapBox pod do this.  I'm still pre-1.0 on cocoapods.

If I dive into my Pods/ folder, I see folders for these pods, however no folders in Target Support Files have been created.

Anyone know how to fix this?

My podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'ECSlidingViewController', '~> 2.0.3'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'Stripe', '~> 5.0'
pod 'FormatterKit', '~> 1.7'
pod 'GPUImage', '~> 0.1'
pod 'PureLayout', '~> 2.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 1.13.2'
pod 'FSCalendar'
pod 'DateTools'
pod 'FZAccordionTableView', '~> 0.1'
pod 'Overcoat', '~> 3.1'
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.2'
pod 'ISO8601'
pod 'Lookback', :configurations => ['Debug']
pod 'LookbackSafe', :configurations => ['Release']
pod 'QBValidator', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK', '~> 7.3'
pod 'UAAppReviewManager'
pod 'TSNPeerBluetooth', '~> 1.0'
pod 'TSNAtomicFlag', '~> 1.0'
pod 'TSNExtensions', '~> 1.0'
pod 'CKStringUtils', '~> 2.0'
pod 'CLLocationManager-blocks', '~> 1.3'
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 6.1.0'
pod 'CardIO', '~> 5.3'
pod 'CocoaSecurity'
pod 'SecureNSUserDefaults', '~> 1.0'
pod 'PMTween', '~> 1.3'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.14'

use_frameworks!
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your podfile like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'YourTarget' do
        pod 'ECSlidingViewController', '~> 2.0.3'
        pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
        pod 'Stripe', '~> 5.0'
        ...
        pod 'PMTween', '~> 1.3'
        pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.14'
end
```